# Why is React not updating state and display in real-time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, onclick, use-state

I am having trouble getting my react project to update the "timeRemaining" state in real-time. I understand that it operates asynchronously but I can't figure out how to remedy the issue. The project works as it should except for "timeRemaining" updates one click after it should. For example, it renders:
(Begins at: 25:00) click=>
(Should be: 20:00, Is actually: 25:00) click=>
(Should be: 15:00, Is actually: 20:00)... and so on... How do I handle this latency?

The "timeRemaining" state is updated by the "handleFocusTimeAdd/sub" and the "handleBreakTimeAdd/Sub" functions and is displayed by the "infoComponent".

Here is the entirety of the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classNames from "../utils/class-names";
import useInterval from "../utils/useInterval";
import { minutesToDuration, secondsToDuration } from "../utils/duration";

function Pomodoro() {
  // Timer starts out paused
  const [isTimerRunning, setIsTimerRunning] = useState(false);
  const [focusDuration, setFocusDuration] = useState(1500);
  const [breakDuration, setBreakDuration] = useState(300);
  const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(focusDuration);
  const [onBreak, setOnBreak] = useState(false);
  const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);

  // Update every second if timer is running
  useInterval(
    () => {
      setTimeRemaining((timeRemaining) => timeRemaining - 1);
      play();
    },
    isTimerRunning ? 1000 : null
  );

  // Handle the PLAY button
  function playPause() {
    setIsTimerRunning((prevState) => !prevState);
    setShowInfo(true);
  }

  // Handle PLAY
  function play() {
    if (timeRemaining === 0) {
      if (onBreak) {
        setTimeRemaining((timeRemaining) => timeRemaining + focusDuration);
        setOnBreak(false);
      }
      if (!onBreak) {
        setTimeRemaining((timeRemaining) => timeRemaining + breakDuration);
        setOnBreak(true);
      }
    }
  }

  // Handle the STOP button
  const handleStopBtn = () => {
    setIsTimerRunning(false);
    setFocusDuration(1500);
    setBreakDuration(300);
    setTimeRemaining(1500);
    setShowInfo(false);
  };

  // Handle the focus duration view SUBTRACT
  const handleFocusTimeSub = (focusDuration) => {
    if (focusDuration > 300) {
      setFocusDuration((focusDuration) => focusDuration - 300);
    } else {
      setFocusDuration((focusDuration) => focusDuration);
    }
    setTimeRemaining(focusDuration)
    return focusDuration;
  };

  // Handle the focus duration view ADD
  const handleFocusTimeAdd = (focusDuration) => {
    if (focusDuration < 3600) {
      setFocusDuration((focusDuration) => focusDuration + 300);
    } else {
      setFocusDuration((focusDuration) => focusDuration);
    }
    setTimeRemaining(focusDuration)
    return focusDuration;
  };

  // Handle the break duration view SUBTRACT
  const handleBreakTimeSub = (breakDuration) => {
    if (breakDuration > 60) {
      setBreakDuration((breakDuration) => breakDuration - 60);
    } else {
      setBreakDuration((breakDuration) => breakDuration);
    }
    return breakDuration;
  };

  // Handle the break duration view ADD
  const handleBreakTimeAdd = (breakDuration) => {
    if (breakDuration < 900) {
      setBreakDuration((breakDuration) => breakDuration + 60);
    } else {
      setBreakDuration((breakDuration) => breakDuration);
    }
    return breakDuration;
  };

  const infoComponent = () => {
    if (showInfo) {
      if (onBreak) {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <h2 data-testid="session-title">
                  On Break for {secondsToDuration(breakDuration)} minutes
                </h2>
                <p className="lead" data-testid="session-sub-title">
                  {secondsToDuration(timeRemaining)} remaining
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <div className="progress" style={{ height: "20px" }}>
                  <div
                    className="progress-bar"
                    role="progressbar"
                    aria-valuemin="0"
                    aria-valuemax="100"
                    aria-valuenow="0" // TODO: Increase aria-valuenow as elapsed time increases
                    style={{ width: "0%" }} // TODO: Increase width % as elapsed time increases
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
      if (!onBreak) {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <h2 data-testid="session-title">
                  Focusing for {secondsToDuration(focusDuration)} minutes
                </h2>
                <p className="lead" data-testid="session-sub-title">
                  {secondsToDuration(timeRemaining)} remaining
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <div className="progress" style={{ height: "20px" }}>
                  <div
                    className="progress-bar"
                    role="progressbar"
                    aria-valuemin="0"
                    aria-valuemax="100"
                    aria-valuenow="0" // TODO: Increase aria-valuenow as elapsed time increases
                    style={{ width: "0%" }} // TODO: Increase width % as elapsed time increases
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    return null;
  };

  return (
    <div className="pomodoro">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <div className="input-group input-group-lg mb-2">
            <span className="input-group-text" data-testid="duration-focus">
              Focus Duration: {secondsToDuration(focusDuration)}
            </span>
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button
                onClick={() => handleFocusTimeSub(focusDuration)}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-testid="decrease-focus"
              >
                <span className="oi oi-minus" />
              </button>

              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  handleFocusTimeAdd(focusDuration);
                }}
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-testid="increase-focus"
              >
                <span className="oi oi-plus" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col">
          <div className="float-right">
            <div className="input-group input-group-lg mb-2">
              <span className="input-group-text" data-testid="duration-break">
                Break Duration: {secondsToDuration(breakDuration)}
              </span>
              <div className="input-group-append">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleBreakTimeSub(breakDuration)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-testid="decrease-break"
                >
                  <span className="oi oi-minus" />
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleBreakTimeAdd(breakDuration)}
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-testid="increase-break"
                >
                  <span className="oi oi-plus" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <div
            className="btn-group btn-group-lg mb-2"
            role="group"
            aria-label="Timer controls"
          >
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              data-testid="play-pause"
              title="Start or pause timer"
              onClick={playPause}
            >
              <span
                className={classNames({
                  oi: true,
                  "oi-media-play": !isTimerRunning,
                  "oi-media-pause": isTimerRunning,
                })}
              />
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={handleStopBtn}
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-secondary"
              title="Stop the session"
            >
              <span className="oi oi-media-stop" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>{infoComponent()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Pomodoro;
```

Thanks for the help! I'm new to React and still working out the kinks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're accessing the wrong reference to a value inside your callback. I'll rename the variables in your `handleFocusTimeSub` callback to expose the error.

```
const handleFocusTimeSub = (inputFocusDuration) => {
  if (inputFocusDuration > 300) {
    setFocusDuration((stateFocusDuration) => stateFocusDuration - 300);
  } else {
    setFocusDuration((stateFocusDuration) => stateFocusDuration);
  }
  setTimeRemaining(inputFocusDuration);
  return inputFocusDuration;
};
```

You likely meant to pass the new state of focusDuration to `setTimeRemaining`.

```
const handleFocusTimeSub = (inputFocusDuration) => {
  if (inputFocusDuration > 300) {
    setFocusDuration(
      (stateFocusDuration) => (
        setTimeRemaining(stateFocusDuration - 300),
        stateFocusDuration - 300
      )
    );
  } else {
    setFocusDuration(
      (stateFocusDuration) => (
        setTimeRemaining(stateFocusDuration),
        stateFocusDuration
      )
    );
  }
  return inputFocusDuration;
};
```

`handleFocusTimeAdd` has the same bug in it and the fix is the same, too.

The fix I showed you is the minimal change to make it work. To avoid these kinds of bugs in the future you'll want to keep state variables that need to know about each  other in a shared reducer instead of separate state hooks.